# Why reject Null Hypothesis when p value< alpha?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, z-score

As per statistical literature, there seems to be this understanding that given a p value less than alpha, we are to reject the null hypothesis.

The way I am interpreting this is that is the critical region, as defined by the alpha is the 'False Rejection' (TYPE 1 error) zone and constitutes the error threshold, why then p-value for a sample that is less than the alpha and within the error zone results in rejection of the null hypothesis?

Another line of thought - if the p-value is a way of saying how extreme a test statistic is for our sample data and seems to have a low probability, then how does it constitute evidence against the null hypothesis? 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The p-value is calculated under the null model. Hence if the test statistic that was observed or a larger value has a low probability under the null model, then it suggests that the null model is unlikely to have been the model that generated the observed data.

Answer (score 0):

The "alpha" ($\alpha$) is set a priori to be the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis **when the null hypothesis is true** (the Type I error as you stated).  If, after conducting your statistical test, the $p$-value is found to be less than $\alpha$, this shows that, under the assumed null hypothesis, the probability you'd observe a test statistic as large (or larger) as the one you did, is very small.  Something with such a small small probability of occuring should be considered suspicious.  How could something be observed when it's so unlikely?  Two things could have happened:

1)  The assumption, under the null hypothesis is wrong (so you reject it/fail to accept it); or

2)  You got a very unlucky result.  This is simply the risk you are willing to take and you should set your $\alpha$/critical region accordingly when you set up your test.  If you can tolerate more risk, set $\alpha$ to be larger.  If you can't, set $\alpha$ to be smaller.

Comment: "likelihood you'd observe a test statistic as large" should be "probability you'd observe a test statistic as large". "likelihood" has a specific meaning and doesn't apply here.

Comment: That's a fair point, @A.Donda.  I fell into the trap of interchanging everyday English with statistical terminology.  The "likelihood" I mentioned above, should be taken to mean the everyday English version of it (i.e. probability).